# app crashes before the request is sent to the server

Tags: c#, android, file-upload, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

I'm building an android app with Xamarin which communicates with an ASP.net server's API. I'm trying to upload a file to the server using the following lines of code:

```
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFile(byte[] file)
    {
        var progress = new System.Net.Http.Handlers.ProgressMessageHandler();

        //progress.HttpSendProgress += progress_HttpSendProgress;

        using (var client = HttpClientFactory.Create(progress))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(GlobalVariables.host);

            // Set the Accept header for BSON.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/bson"));

            var request = new uploadFileModel { data = file, dateCreated = DateTime.Now, fileName = "myvideooo.mp4", username = "psyoptica" };

            // POST using the BSON formatter.
            MediaTypeFormatter bsonFormatter = new BsonMediaTypeFormatter();
            var m = client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize;
            var result = await client.PostAsync("api/media/upload", request, bsonFormatter);
            return result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
```

The app crashes before the server receives the request. The file I'm trying to upload could be a video or an audio file. The server receives the request after the app has crashed. This works fine on the local server but the crash happens with the live server. My server side code looks like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("upload")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Upload(uploadFileModel model)
    {


        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string thumbname = "";
            string resizedthumbname = Guid.NewGuid() + "_yt.jpg";

            string FfmpegPath = Encoding_Settings.FFMPEGPATH;

            string tempFilePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/tempuploads"), model.fileName);
            string pathToFiles = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/tempuploads");
            string pathToThumbs = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/contents/member/" + model.username + "/thumbs");
            string finalPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/contents/member/" + model.username + "/flv");
            string resizedthumb = Path.Combine(pathToThumbs, resizedthumbname);


            var outputPathVid = new MediaFile { Filename = Path.Combine(finalPath, model.fileName) };
            var inputPathVid = new MediaFile { Filename = Path.Combine(pathToFiles, model.fileName) };
            int maxWidth = 380;
            int maxHeight = 360;

            var namewithoutext = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.Combine(pathToFiles, model.fileName));
            thumbname = model.VideoThumbName;
            string oldthumbpath = Path.Combine(pathToThumbs, thumbname);


            var fileName = model.fileName;

            File.WriteAllBytes(tempFilePath, model.data);


            if (model.fileName.Contains("audio"))
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(finalPath, model.fileName), model.data);

                string audio_thumb = "mic_thumb.jpg";
                string destination = Path.Combine(pathToThumbs, audio_thumb);
                string source = Path.Combine(pathToFiles, audio_thumb);
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(destination))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Copy(source, destination, true);
                }


                Video_Struct vd = new Video_Struct();
                vd.CategoryID = 0; // store categoryname or term instead of category id
                vd.Categories = "";
                vd.UserName = model.username;
                vd.Title = "";
                vd.Description = "";
                vd.Tags = "";
                vd.OriginalVideoFileName = model.fileName;
                vd.VideoFileName = model.fileName;
                vd.ThumbFileName = "mic_thumb.jpg";
                vd.isPrivate = 0;
                vd.AuthKey = "";
                vd.isEnabled = 1;
                vd.Response_VideoID = 0; // video responses
                vd.isResponse = 0;
                vd.isPublished = 1;
                vd.isReviewed = 1;
                vd.Thumb_Url = "none";
                //vd.FLV_Url = flv_url;
                vd.Embed_Script = "";
                vd.isExternal = 0; // website own video, 1: embed video
                vd.Type = 0;
                vd.YoutubeID = "";
                vd.isTagsreViewed = 1;
                vd.Mode = 0; // filter videos based on website sections
                long videoid = VideoBLL.Process_Info(vd, false);
            }
            else
            {
                using (var engine = new Engine())
                {
                    engine.GetMetadata(inputPathVid);

                    // Saves the frame located on the 15th second of the video.
                    var outputPathThumb = new MediaFile { Filename = Path.Combine(pathToThumbs, thumbname+".jpg") };
                    var options = new ConversionOptions { Seek = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), CustomHeight = 360, CustomWidth = 380 };
                    engine.GetThumbnail(inputPathVid, outputPathThumb, options);

                }

                Image image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(pathToThumbs, thumbname+".jpg"));

                //var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
                //var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
                //var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

                var newWidth = (int)(maxWidth);
                var newHeight = (int)(maxHeight);

                var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
                Graphics.FromImage(newImage).DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(newImage);
                bmp.Save(Path.Combine(pathToThumbs, thumbname+"_resized.jpg"));

                //File.Delete(Path.Combine(pathToThumbs, thumbname));

                using (var engine = new Engine())
                {

                    var conversionOptions = new ConversionOptions
                    {
                        VideoSize = VideoSize.Hd720,
                        AudioSampleRate = AudioSampleRate.Hz44100,
                        VideoAspectRatio = VideoAspectRatio.Default
                    };

                    engine.GetMetadata(inputPathVid);
                    engine.Convert(inputPathVid, outputPathVid, conversionOptions);

                }

                File.Delete(tempFilePath);

                Video_Struct vd = new Video_Struct();
                vd.CategoryID = 0; // store categoryname or term instead of category id
                vd.Categories = "";
                vd.UserName = model.username;
                vd.Title = "";
                vd.Description = "";
                vd.Tags = "";
                vd.Duration = inputPathVid.Metadata.Duration.ToString();
                vd.Duration_Sec = Convert.ToInt32(inputPathVid.Metadata.Duration.Seconds.ToString());
                vd.OriginalVideoFileName = model.fileName;
                vd.VideoFileName = model.fileName;
                vd.ThumbFileName = thumbname+"_resized.jpg";
                vd.isPrivate = 0;
                vd.AuthKey = "";
                vd.isEnabled = 1;
                vd.Response_VideoID = 0; // video responses
                vd.isResponse = 0;
                vd.isPublished = 1;
                vd.isReviewed = 1;
                vd.Thumb_Url = "none";
                //vd.FLV_Url = flv_url;
                vd.Embed_Script = "";
                vd.isExternal = 0; // website own video, 1: embed video
                vd.Type = 0;
                vd.YoutubeID = "";
                vd.isTagsreViewed = 1;
                vd.Mode = 0; // filter videos based on website sections
                //vd.ContentLength = f_contentlength;
                vd.GalleryID = 0;
                long videoid = VideoBLL.Process_Info(vd, false);

            }




            return result;
        }

        else
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted"));
        }

    }`
```

What am I doing wrong here that's making the app crash. Is there a better way to do this?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: add crash reports.

Comment: The app is published on the google play store. Let me check if the console generates crash reports

Comment: Google play store console doesn't show any crashes. I don't know how to run the diagnostics to check for stack tracing. Can u please help me with how I might be able to do it?

Comment: add crash reporting (Hockey App, Crashyltics, etc) to your app.

Comment: okay thanks. I'll do that

Comment: Can you replicate the crash in your dev environment?

Comment: I'm doing that now. I have both the app and the server published. I was testing it in the local environment and everything was working fine so I thought it would work with the published app as well but apparently that's not the case

Comment: does your app have INTERNET_PERMISSIONS enable in the manifest?

Comment: Did you actually test the release build before publishing it? You are most likely hitting a linker issue or something like that.

Comment: Okay I've tested it on my dev environment. I'm getting 500 internal server when the debugger hits 'File.WriteAllBytes' on the server side.It might have to do with the permissions.

Comment: @Jason yes I have internet permissions enabled in the manifest

Comment: Checking the server directory revealed that the file path didn't exist where I am trying to write the file data:/